# Javascript function isn't running

Tags: javascript

Have been trying to fix this for the past hour.

Here goes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openAd(adType, urlToGo) {
        pageTracker._trackPageview(adType);
        window.open(urlToGo, '_blank');
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Anyone have any idea why this doesn't work?

Called it like `onclick="openAd('/Ads/MMA_Front_Page.com', 'http://www.anrdoezrs.net/click-4706163-10919130');"`

I uploaded a live version at:

http://www.easymuaythai.com/

Comment: open your browser's javascript console, and see what the error it returns sais.

Comment: Are you using Firebug (Firefox) or the Webkit inspector (Safari and Chrome)? Both are excellent tools for debugging Javascript. A disclosure of the errors or behavior exhibited from those tools would make your question more clear.

Comment: Aren't you passing two arguments where your function accepts only one?

Comment: Also, where is 'this.href' to come from?  I think you should add a second param 'href' and then call window.open(href), but without seeing the page I couldn't say for sure.  +1 on using Firebug or Web Tools.

Comment: Sorry i had the wrong code posted. I am using firebug, it doesn't give an error, it just doesn't open the new window.

Comment: Nice code, it does three things my browser is configured to block: (1) analytics (2) ads (3) popups in general.

Comment: Try commenting out the first line inside the openAd() function ( pageTracker._trackPageview(adType); ). If it works, you know your problem is with that line. You'll have to track down where the pageTracker object and _trackPageview methods are coming from.

Comment: It probably isn't helping that you have declared the function twice in your code.

Comment: it actually works for me, it opens a new tab. You aren't collecting easy banner clicks, are you? :P

Comment: It does work if I comment out the first line. Here is where the code is coming from: http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js. Beats me what it does thou.

Comment: There's not enough information to say what's going wrong. Set a breakpoint in `openAd`, which you can do in firebug or with the [debugger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) statement. Make sure that the built-in pop-up blocker and no extension (e.g. any adblocker) is preventing the new window or tab from opening.

Comment: I have just decided not to open in a new window, too much work to make it work, and i didn't know it could get blocked by popup.

Comment: Also, comments aren't meant for extended discussions and understanding the question shouldn't require reading the comments. Try using a [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) room to get the necessary information to reproduce the issue, hen edit your question so it contains the relevant information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have went to your page in Opera 11.60 and called `openAd('/Ads/MMA_Front_Page.com', 'http://www.anrdoezrs.net/click-4706163-10919130');` through [Dragonfly](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/) and the information was displayed in my browser that the popup has been blocked. When I click to display the popup anyway, the new windows with your add target is displayed correctly.

Thus, I would suggest to seek different method to open the ad or accept the fact you may be blocked by popup / ad blocker.

Comment: I guess a regular link is in order? I didn't know it countet as a popup.

Comment: Calling window.open != regular link.

Comment: Yea i know, i just used regular href

Answer (score 2):

if your problem is that the browser loads the url in the href as well as opens a new window then you need to add `return false` as so:

```
onclick="openAd('/Ads/MMA_Front_Page.com', 'http://www.anrdoezrs.net/click-4706163-10919130'); return false;"
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know i had to place it there.